# How to assign a Photoshop designed button in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have designed a main menu screen for my app, including the buttons and background and I want to know is it possible to link these buttons directly from background without putting each one of them in draw-able folder?
or do I have to put each one individually?

Comment: `do i have to put each one individually?` **YES**.

Comment: means i can't just paste that fully customized background image?

Comment: You need separate **PNG**s. You can't just use a **PSD**.

Comment: what is more sufficient way to add PNGs? writing title on images or writing the title in android studio? sorry if its a stupid question but am really a beginner as u can see :)

Comment: A simple background without any other pixel (the text) is smaller. You can add the text later (very easy, if you use a TextView as a Button).

Answer (score 0):

same as eclipse put png file in drawable folder and set ::

```
android:background="@drawable/imagename"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste all the files into your `drawable` folder and then link them to your xml attributes using.

```
android:background="@drawable/filename"
```